# Using memcached with a dynamic django backend

Tags: django, memcached

My Django backend is always dynamic. It serves an iOS app similar to that of Instagram and Vine where users upload photos/videos and their followers can comment and like the content. Just for the sake of this question, imagine my backend serves an iOS app that is exactly like Instagram.

Many sources claim that using memcached can improve performance because it decreases the amount of hits that are made to the database.

My question is, for a backend that is already in dynamic in nature (always changing since users are uploading new pictures, commenting, liking, following new users etc..) what can I possibly cache?

It's a problem I've been thinking about for quite some time. I could cache the user profile data, but other than that, I don't know where else memcached would be useful.

Other sources mentioned using it everywhere in the backend where a 'GET' call is made but then I would need to set a suitable time limit to expire the cache since the app is always dynamic. What are your solutions and suggestions for getting around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You would cache whatever is being most frequently accessed from your Database. Make a list of the most frequent requests to get data from the database and cache the data in that priority.

1. Cache the most frequent requests based on category of the pictures
2. Cache based on users - power users go into cache (those which do a lot of data access)
3. Cache the most recent inserts (in case you have a page which shows the recently added posts/pictures)

I am sure you can come up with more scenarios. I am positive memcached (or any other caching) will help, even though your app is very 'dynamic'.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Sid, I've never actually tried memcached before so this is going to be my first shot at it, hopefully, it works out well for me in my stack

Comment: Sure. Just remember the 1-MB limit. You can always chunk your request and store with a manifest if your requests exceed that. Good luck.